# Looking for javascript plugin about drop down element from input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am looking for something like stackoverflow Tags input that will show me the suggestion list after I input something.

I don't mind jquery plugin as long as it meet my needs.

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to offer the opportunity to select multiple values in an autocomplete field, use the Autocomplete "Multiple" variant from jQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Hope this helps.